# How do I fix this do-while loop so console program prompts the user before automatically closing?

Tags: c, calculator, do-while, repeat

When I run this code everything runs smoothly until the last part. After the question "Would you like to repeat?" is asked, the console doesn't prompt the user for an answer and instead ends to program.

How do I edit the code for the do-while loop so that the user is prompted for an answer instead of closing the program automatically? I feel like its an issue with format specifiers, I'm new to this and have been having issues with that. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double num1, num2;
    char operation, repeat = "y";
    printf("This is a calculator.");

    do {
        printf("\nWould you like to multiply(*), divide(/), add(+) or subtract(-) the two numbers you will soon input? \n");
        scanf("%c", &operation);
        printf("Please enter the first number you would like to deal with. \n");
        scanf("%lf", &num1);
        printf("And the second?\n");
        scanf("%lf", &num2);

        switch (operation)
        {
        case '*':
            printf("The product of %1.2lf and %1.2lf is %1.2lf.\n",
                   num1, num2, num1 * num2);
            break;
        case '/':
            printf("The quotient of %1.2lf and %1.2lf is %1.2lf.\n",
                   num1, num2, num1 / num2);
            break;
        case '+':
            printf("The sum of %1.2lf and %1.2lf is %1.2lf.\n",
                   num1, num2, num1 + num2);
            break;
        case '-':
            printf("The difference of %1.2lf and %1.2lf is %1.2lf.\n",
                   num1, num2, num1 - num2);
            break;
        }
        printf("Would you like to repeat?(y/n)\n");
        scanf("%c", &repeat);
    } while (repeat == "y" || repeat == "Y");
}
```

Comment: Characters should be taken between single `'`

Comment: You have *two* problems. One is your comparison of a single character against *strings*. The other is that you don't skip leading white-space (like the newlines left over from previous input).

Comment: You should check the return value of `scanf`

Comment: It's common practice when writing code to add a space after a comma and around operators, see my edit of your question. It makes code way easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a newline character left in `stdin` from the previous input operation. Your

> ```
> scanf("%c",&repeat);
> ```

reads that newline character because the conversion specifier `%c` doesn't skip whitespace characters. Use

```
scanf(" %c", &repeat);
```

to skip leading whitespace.

---

In C and C++ single characters are enclosed in single quotes.

```
char ch;
ch == "A";
```

would compare the value of `ch` to the address of the string literal `"A"`.

So ...

> ```
> while(repeat=="y"||repeat=="Y");
> ```

*~>*

```
while(repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y');
```

and

> ```
> char operation, repeat="y";
> ```

*~>*

```
char operation, repeat = 'y';
```

Your compiler should have warned you about that. If not you should increase the warning level of your Compiler.

---

You also might want to check for division by zero which is undefined.

---

One last thing: `printf()` doesn't care about the length specifier `l` in `%lf`, it's the same as `%f` because of default parameter propagation. A `float` argument in a call to a function that takes a variable number of arguments is always converted to `double` before it is passed to the function. So there is only `%f` for `printf()`.

---

PS:
as [Cacahuete Frito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6872717/cacahuete-frito) said in the comments:

> You should check the return value of `scanf()`

Yes, you should. Never trust the user.

Comment: I still like to use `%lf` for printing a `double` and `%f` for a `float`. That way I don't have to think if I'm in a `scanf` or in a `printf`.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Whatever floats your boat. Just be aware that it was not allowed before C99 and C++11.

Comment: How do I check the return value? I tried this originally using isdigit() but I couldn't get isdigit() to work with the float values.

Comment: @eltusen `scanf()` returns the number of successful assignments.

Comment: sorry, i'm a beginner i dont really know what that means.

Comment: does that mean if a long float isn't inputted then it will return 0?

Comment: Yes. But please, consult some documentation: [`scanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) (scroll down to "Return Value")